# PubSub to BigQuery - Dataflow/Beam template in Python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there any Python template/script (existing or roadmap) for Dataflow/Beam to read from PubSub and write to BigQuery?
As per the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubsubscriptiontobigquery), there is only a [Java template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java).

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an example here [Pub/Sub to BigQuery sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam#pubsub-to-bigquery-sample) with [template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/dataflow/flex-templates/streaming_beam/streaming_beam.py):

> An Apache Beam streaming pipeline example.
>
> It reads JSON encoded
> messages from Pub/Sub, transforms the message data, and writes the
> results to BigQuery.

Here's another example that shows how to handle invalid message from pubsub into a different table in Bigquery :

```py
class ParseMessage(beam.DoFn):
    OUTPUT_ERROR_TAG = 'error'
    
    def process(self, line):
        """
        Extracts fields from json message
        :param line: pubsub message
        :return: have two outputs:
            - main: parsed data
            - error: error message
        """
        try:
            parsed_row = _ # parse json message to corresponding bgiquery table schema
            yield data_row
        except Exception as error:
            error_row = _ # build you error schema here
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.OUTPUT_ERROR_TAG, error_row)
        

def run(options, input_subscription, output_table, output_error_table):
    """
    Build and run Pipeline
    :param options: pipeline options
    :param input_subscription: input PubSub subscription
    :param output_table: id of an output BigQuery table
    :param output_error_table: id of an output BigQuery table for error messages
    """

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
        # Read from PubSub
        rows, error_rows = \
            (pipeline | 'Read from PubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
             # Adapt messages from PubSub to BQ table
             | 'Parse JSON messages' >> beam.ParDo(ParseMessage()).with_outputs(ParseMessage.OUTPUT_ERROR_TAG,
                                                                                main='rows')
             )

        _ = (rows | 'Write to BigQuery'
             >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(output_table,
                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                        insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR
                                        )
             )

        _ = (error_rows | 'Write errors to BigQuery'
             >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(output_error_table,
                                        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                        insert_retry_strategy=RetryStrategy.RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR
                                        )
             )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input_subscription', required=True,
        help='Input PubSub subscription of the form "/subscriptions/<PROJECT>/<SUBSCRIPTION>".')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output_table', required=True,
        help='Output BigQuery table for results specified as: PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.')
    parser.add_argument(
        '--output_error_table', required=True,
        help='Output BigQuery table for errors specified as: PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE or DATASET.TABLE.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    run(pipeline_options, known_args.input_subscription, known_args.output_table, known_args.output_error_table)
```

Comment: Many thanks ! Since you add details.. May I ask if there is a built-in way to allow for schema evolution (for example combined with insert_retry_strategy) ? The examples found so far seem quite manual, but maybe also outdated. Glad to ask a new question on that. Just let me know. Thanks !

Comment: @py-r I'm not sure about this, but as per what I've seen you need to handle this with custom logic (something like différent table destinations for each type of schema?). If there is nothing about this on SO I think you can ask it as another question, maybe someone has implemented it.